# Need recursive sql in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a recursive query as below:

```
with addresses as

(

  select cust_id,address addr from

  (

  select 10 cust_id,'9 Help Street, Level 4' address from dual union all

  select 11 cust_id,'22 Victoria Street' address from dual union all

  select 12 cust_id,'1495 Franklin Str.' address from dual union all

  select 13 cust_id,'30 Hasivim St.,Petah-Tikva' address from dual union all

  select 14 cust_id,'2 Jakaranda St' address from dual union all

  select 15 cust_id,'61, Science Park Rd' address from dual union all

  select 16 cust_id,'61, Social park road.' address from dual union all

  select 17 cust_id,'Av. Hermanos Escobar 5756' address from dual union all

  select 18 cust_id,'Ave. Hermanos Escobar 5756' address from dual union all

  select 19 cust_id,'8000 W FLORISSANT Ave.' address from dual union all

  select 20 cust_id,'8600 MEMORIAL PKWY SW' address from dual union all

  select 21 cust_id,'8200 FLORISSANTMEMORIALWAYABOVE SW' address from dual union all

  select 22 cust_id,'8600 MEMORIALFLORISSANT PKWY SW.' address from dual

  ) t1

),

 replacements as

  (

  select id,to_str,from_string from_str from

  (

  select 1 id,'St' to_str,'Street' from_string from dual union all

 select 2 id,'St' to_str,'St' from_string from dual union all

 select 3 id,'St' to_str,'Strit' from_string from dual union all

 select 4 id,'St' to_str,'Str' from_string from dual union all

 select 5 id,'Rd' to_str,'Rd.' from_string from dual union all

 select 6 id,'Rd' to_str,'road' from_string from dual union all

 select 7 id,'Av' to_str,'Av.' from_string from dual union all

 select 8 id,'Av' to_str,'Ave' from_string from dual union all

 select 9 id,'Av' to_str,'Avenue' from_string from dual union all

 select 10 id,'Av' to_str,'Aven.' from_string from dual union all

 select 11 id,'West' to_str,'W' from_string from dual union all

 select 12 id,'South West' to_str,'SW' from_string from dual

 ) t2

),

 r(cust_id,addr,test_addr,l) as 

 (

   select cust_id,addr,regexp_replace(addr,'(^|\W)' || from_str || '(\W|$)','\1' || to_str || '\2') test_addr,

     id - 1

     from  

     addresses,

     replacements

     where id = (select count(*) from replacements)

   union all

     select cust_id,addr,regexp_replace(test_addr,'(^|\W)' || from_str || '(\W|$)','\1' || to_str || '\2') test_addr,

     l - 1

     from r,

     replacements

     where id = l

  )

 select cust_id,addr,test_addr,l

 from r

 where l=0

 ;
```

present output:

[image]

Query not working as expected for cust_id like 16,18,22. in cust_id dot is there after road but still it changes to Rd.

I need 2 queries...one with exact match including dot and the other sql having match with dot or without dot.

The expect out put for first sql with exact match:
[image]

The expected output with second sql with or without dot:
[image]

Thanks

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

What about cust_id 12 in expected output of exact match? Is that expected?  Did you try `\s` instead of `\W` ?

Comment: Yes, you are right...it was my mistake...it should be Str. in addr and in test_addr as well.     
 12 1495 Franklin Str. 1495 Franklin Str.

Comment: I tried with /s  and it works if the replacement word is at starting or end of the string. if it is in the middle of the string, it doesn't work. for example: 10 9 Help Street, Level 4       
9 Help Street, Level 4....can you take a look?

Comment: Will inserting another row in replacements help?  


select 13 id,'St' to_str,'Street,' from_string from dual

Comment: But I can't insert all combinations into the replacements table. I just go with what is provided by the customer but output is handled in sql.

Comment: so dot character is the problem. Please let me know if this statement is right ? "Any word in the text with dot at the end should not be replaced others can be replaced".

Please try with regexp like below to see if this is the expected output. 
`code`
regexp_replace(addr,'(^|\s)' || from_str || '([\,]\s|$)','\1' || to_str || '\2') 
`code`

This requires to mention all the possible characters next to comma. I dont know whether this is the right way. just an attempt.

[Fiddle Reference]:
(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bc488c3099b5da4935564da2ef716a90)

Comment: this is what I am looking for:  ---if the replacements.from_string = word in addresses.addr matches...replace with to_string----                                                                                                                     
1). if there is a dot on both sides of equal then replace with to_string. ----2). if there is a dot at the end of the word in addresses.addr and no dot in the replacements.from_string then replace and add the dot at the end. I will try your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: I used your suggestion of regexp....the result is added to my question as my answer as I the result is included as an image.

Comment: for cust_id:12,18,19 not working..ex:  12 1495 Franklin Str. 495 Franklin Str. ----expecting St. instead of Str. - could you check?

Comment: This is confusing a bit. What is the problem with 18?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230551/discussion-between-praveen-and-satya-v).